# How to create a page when clicking a post link using php

Tags: php, mysql

Ok i have created a forum posting page where they input the data then its stored in a table then echoed out on a different page with links but i want the links to generate a page with the post then i can allow the user to comment but i have an idea for the comments i just need help with the generation of the page. The code where the user can click...

```
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123");
            $database = mysql_select_db('phplogin');
            $data = "SELECT * FROM forum ORDER BY time DESC";
            $result = mysql_query($data);

            if($connect) {

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<div class='post'>" . "<div class='leftside'>" . "<h3 class='by'>" . $row['user'] . "</h3>" . "<h6 class='when'>" . $row['time'] . "</h6>" . "</div>" . "<div class='middle'>" . "<h3 class='questiontitle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . "</h3>" . "<p class='description'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) . "</p>" . "</div>" . "<div class='rightside'>" . "<a href='#' class='answer'>Answer it</a>" . "</div>" . "</div>";
                }
```

Comment: I appreciate that you're just starting out, but now would be a really good time to get to grips with PDO and/or mysqli methods

Comment: i will do that when i go into doing 'proper websites' this is just a forum for my computer science class as they aren't as good as me in web creation, thanks anyway.